# Looping using rest operator gives duplicate objects in the array

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have an array of objects

```
const w=[ {widgetId: 13, widgetKey: "currentMonthAvgSalesOrders", widgetName: "Current month average sales and orders", title: "Current month average sales and orders", type: "card", …},
{widgetId: 12, widgetKey: "orderSalesCurrentFinancialYear", widgetName: "Sales and orders of the current financial year", title: "Sales and orders of current financial year", type: "card", …},
{widgetId: 28, widgetKey: "currentMonthAvgSalesPerSectorPerDay", widgetName: "Current Month Average Sales per sector per day", title: "Current Month Average Sales per sector per day", type: "card", …},
{widgetId: 28, widgetKey: "currentMonthAvgSalesPerSectorPerDay", widgetName: "Current Month Average Sales per sector per day", title: "Current Month Average Sales per sector per day", type: "card", …}]
```

I am storing it in a setState function which is initially an empty array by filtering based on criteria. I am using the rest operator to store the data in the setState but it gives me duplicate data which keeps adding up each time I call the `useEffect` hook.

My `useState` hook:

```
const [dataCards,setDataCards]=useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    if(Object.keys(userWidgetDetails).length>0){
    
     const {widgets}=userWidgetDetails;
     let dataArray=widgets.filter(s=>s.type==='card')
     setDataCards([...dataCards,...dataArray])
    }
     }, [userWidgetDetails,customizeWidget])
```

what is wrong with this implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
setDataCards(dataCards => [...dataCards, ...dataArray])
```

This will allow you to make use of the current values of the state variable, which is the argument passed in to the `setDataCards` function.

More info: https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#setstate

Comment: another way of the same implementation but gives me the same result.why this implementation duplicates the objects all the time is where i am getting stuck

Comment: The code you provided doesn't explain how exactly you're using this component. If there was any reason for which it loaded twice, it could explain the duplication.